# Why aren't the function values being passed to the lambda function and evaluating?

Tags: lambda, lisp

So I'm trying to construct an interpreter that can handle user defined lambda functions which can have a variable number of arguments. Code looks a little like this:

```
((lambda (x &optional y z) (func_body)) args))
```

Right now, the result I can get is the proper function without it being evaluated; for example, if I define `square X = (* X X)` and run my interpreter I get:

```
(* X X)
```

What I require is the above function after being evaluated. I have tried things like:

```
(let ((func (lambda (x &optional y z) (func_body))))
     (apply/funcall func args))

((lambda (x &optional y z) (func_body)) args)
```

However they still yield a result I am not after. I trying to have it so when I define `square X = (* X X)`, and put in `(square 4)` I get:

```
16
```

Any guidance on what I am missing?

edit: the args clause are generated by `(cdr/car Y)` or another function. Also, if I try to generate a lambda list using a function lisp complains it's not a symbol, any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error I see is the syntax of [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm): it should be

```
(let ((func (lambda (x) (* x x))))
  (funcall func 4))
==> 16
```

[Lambda](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ac.htm) also works:

```
((lambda (x) (* x x)) 5)
==> 25
```

Now, if your body is stored in a [variable](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm), it becomes slightly more contrived:

```
(defparameter *square* '(* x x))
(funcall (coerce `(lambda (x) ,*square*) 'function) 3)
==> 9
```

However, it would be a much better idea to keep your code as a [`lambda`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_lambda.htm) from get go:

```
(defparameter *square* (lambda (x) (* x x)))
(funcall *square* 4)
==> 16
```

Comment: I should mention the args clause are generated by (cdr/car Y) or another function. Much of the lambda function is now that I think about it. Basically, the command line reads something like 

`>'square X = (* X X) 'square 4`    
result: `> 16`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> ((lambda (x &optional y z) (func_body)) args)

Examples:

```
CL-USER 111 > ((lambda (x &optional (y 0) (z 0))
                 (+ x y z))
               1
               2
               3)
6

CL-USER 112 > (apply (lambda (x &optional (y 0) (z 0))
                       (+ x y z))
                     '(1 2 3))
6
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating an interpreter where you do not rely on the host `eval` (`coerce`) you store the lambda with the current environment as data. Your `apply` would need to support to make a new frame with the arguments bound to their names based the stored environment. Then the body needs to be evaluated under that environment. Thus you are never using Common Lisp `lambda` macro not `apply` for compound application.

The other answers that suggest using `coerce` won't work with lexical variables in your interpreter.